# Child Div Breaking its Parent's Div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float

I have spent hours trying to prevent one of my child divs from breaking its parent's div.

Link: http://bowenhost.com/wordpress/

Screenshot: [image]

It's the saddads widget / div that keeps breaking.

Feel free to inspect element / firebug on your web browsers to find a solution.

Thanks in advance guys. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the content is with out spaces. so it is treated as single word. give some sentence with space between the words and check

If you want to break the word which has no spaces you can use word wrap of css3

```
.textwidget {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    }
```

Comment: You're right it doesn't break with regular sentences, but isn't it best for content without spaces to be word wrapped anyways? Not breaking its parent's div?

Answer (score 1):

you just make some two new classes for your `HTML` than it will work perfectly see below how i achieved your desired result....and one thing more with this just add **spaces** between your content also... so you will have to give the **space** between the content....

make these two classes for your **HTML**

**CSS**

```
.widget-inner {
    overflow: hidden;

}

.textwidget {
    white-space: pre-wrap;

}
```

see the attached demo image you will get a basic idea how i did

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work if there are no spaces in the word/content.

Comment: @hungerstar so i mentioned in my answer specially you should give the space between your content and you can check my answer with the screenshot also how i achieved the required goal.....

Comment: your answer doesn't account for the fact that the OP may not be able to break up the word/content.  `white-space: pre-wrap;` will only preserve white space.  Insert a space in the middle of that long string.  It will break into two lines with or without your `white-space: pre-wrap;`.  The overflow hidden will just hide the content and not have it conform to the containing DIV.

Answer (score 1):

It will break to a new line if there is a space.  But if there is no space you could look into using these CSS properties.

- *Word Wrap* - `word-wrap: break-word;`,  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap
- *Word Break* - `word-break: break-all;`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

Make sure to check the compatability on those pages.